# Showing default avatar in Friends:mine

Tags: ee2, solspace

I am trying to show a default avatar if the member hasnt uploaded a custom avatar.

Here is my code:

```
{exp:friends:mine reciprocal="y" orderby="screen_name" sort="asc" limit="5" member_group_id="6" member_id="{segment_3}" dynamic="no"}
<li class="network">
  {if friends_avatar_url}
  <a href="{path='volunteers/profile'}/{member_id}/">
    {exp:ce_img:single src="{friends_avatar_url}" width="50" height="50" }
    {friends_screen_name}
  </a>
  {if:else}                  
  <a href="{path='volunteers/profile'}/{member_id}/">
    <img src="{site_url}images/avatars/default_set/default-member-ph.png" width="50" height="50">
    {friends_screen_name}
  </a>
  {/if}
</li>

{if friends_no_results}
<li class="noresults">No Volunteers</li>
{/if}{/exp:friends:mine}
```

Is there a reason why the conditional wouldn't work?

Comment: Seems to work in my testing. What version of Friends and EE are you using? Have you tested the above on a *completely*, *absolutely blank* EE template with *nothing whatsoever on it besides the code*?

Comment: yes tested on blank template with just code with no results. if they have avatar it shows but default doesnt.

i am using EE 2.7.2 and Friends 1.6.3

Comment: When there is no avatar, does the `friends_screen_name` display at least? If so, maybe your img path is just wrong?

Comment: yes the friends_screen_name does show and the image path is correct.

Comment: no other ideas @Solspace ?

Comment: So `{site_url}images/avatars/default_set/default-member-ph.png` does not display? Have you tried hard-coding a URL to the image? Can you access the image directly from the browser? If you can't, maybe you have a permissions or .htaccess issue. Can you show what this URL is here?